# I'm not unlocking anything

Tags: rocket-league

I am playing in a party with friends (not split screen) and yet I'm not unlocking anything. I don't have everything because my inventory has like 6 things in it. Plus my friends have antennas and toppers that I do not. What do I do?

Comment: Any particular game?

Comment: Hi Silence!  What game are you talking about?

Comment: Antennas and toppers makes it sound like Rocket League for sure

Answer (score 7):

You are likely hitting up against the 10 hours/week drop limit. From the patch notes:

> There is a maximum of ten hours of playtime per week that can earn items, so don’t bother trying to idle your way to a full inventory!

Comment: Such a roundabout way of going about things too, just put a cap on the NUMBER of items you can earn, not a playtime cap when the drop rates are entirely chance based.

Comment: It's not that unusual a system - I distinctly remember TF2 working in the same way. That said yeah, maybe just "YOU GET 5 THINGS A WEEK GO NUTS" is the way to go.